# Getting error Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidBucketName when creating bucket

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

I am trying to create a bucket, with help of [aws-sdk-ruby](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) from ruby console. Following is the code I am running in my console:

```
Aws.config.update({
  :region => "myRegion",
  :credentials => Aws::Credentials.new("access_key", "secret_key"),
  :endpoint => "http://Ip",
  :force_path_style => true
  })
  bucket_name = "abc"
  bucket = s3.bucket(bucket_name)
  bucket.create({ acl: "authenticated-read", grant_full_control: "GrantFullControl"})
```

Last line gives this error:

> Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidBucketName:

I dont see this error in the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Errors.html). When can one get such error and how to resolve this?

Comment: The error is derived from `Aws::Errors::ServiceError`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko so how to resolve this, still did not found this in docs, are there some guidelines for bucket name?

Comment: Maybe try with longer bucket name? like `abcdflkfgnfg`

Comment: Yes, there are [bucket name rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev//BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules), but `abc` seems to be a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error.. the main reason why was getting this error because my bucket name was starting with capital letter.. Bucket name always starts with lowercase ..